# Forgot Username Link Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am looking into how to make the "Forgot Username" link to appear on the login page.  According to the PR that added this functionality (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/cd8c8d52e8b1317c5fcf6035c33784386af10654), it looks like it is supposed to show up when you turn on the feature for "Forgot Password".

I have this feature turned on, and the "Forgot Password" link now shows up on the login screen and works correctly.  I still cannot get the "Forgot Username" link to show up.

I cannot find any documentation on this feature.  If someone could point me to the documentation for this or the correct setting in the admin UI, I would appreciate it.

I have tried:

- In Realm Settings -> Login, turning on "Forgot Password"
- In Realm Settings -> Login, trying all possible combinations of "Verify Email", "Login with Email" and "Duplicate Email"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Forgot Username" link has been removed since [this commit](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/05bd92d76580d63183c70318fa6a3c2296b41745#diff-69047e00919272a6a22043a856c3fd92). According to the commit message, this is because Keycloak supported login with email.